# $v$ is an eigen vector iff $v \in \: N(T-\lambda I)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$ , and let $\lambda$ be an eigen value of $T$. A vector $v \in V$ is an eigen value of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$ iff $v \neq 0$ and $v \in N(T - \lambda I)$.

Let us first say , $v$ is an eigen vector of T with corresponding eigen value $\lambda$ ,

=> $T(v) = \lambda v$ => $T(v) - \lambda I =0$, => $(T - \lambda I )(v)=0$

=> $v \in N(T - \lambda I)$

Converse can be done like this only , so , when $v \in N(T - \lambda I)$ , =>  $(T - \lambda I )(v)=0$ and so on..

Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: what does N represent ?

Comment: @Liad $N(A)$ is typically the nullspace or kernel of some operator $A$.

Comment: thanks, Im used to ker , didnt know that.